# Dropdown menu disappears in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, drop-down-menu

A weird problem with a dropdown menu in IE7: http://screenr.com/SNM

The dropdown disappears when the mouse moves to a part that hovers above other layers.

The HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="header">
<ul class="nav>
    <li><a href="">item</a>
    <ul><li><a href="">sub-item</a></li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div><!-- /header-->
<div class="featured"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

The sub-menu is positioned absolutely and has `visibility:hidden`, then it's set to `visible` using jQuery, like so:

```
$(".header ul.nav li").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

I had a problem with the dropdown hiding under other content in IE7, fixed easily by giving the z-index to its parent and other divs:

```
*:first-child+html .header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2 !important;
}

*:first-child+html .content, 
*:first-child+html .main,
*:first-child+html .primary
*:first-child+html .featured {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

Now, I have no idea why the menu disappears when hovered over other divs, you can view the site live here: http://dev.gentlecode.net/ama/ubezpieczenia.html

I would love any help, been staring at this code for ages now without any solution. I guess it's just me tunnel visioning already...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You are missing a comma after `*:first-child+html .primary`, not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 4):

Through dumb luck I think I figured out the solution.

I started adding background colors to different elements in the drop-down menu to see if there were any 'holes' that might be effecting the `:hover` state.

When I added a `background-color:#HEX` to the 2nd-level links in the menu everything started working on IE7.

I then tried using `background-color:transparent` but that unfortunately doesn't work.

Finally I tried it with a transparent background-image and that DOES work.

So the solution is to either add a solid background-color, or a transparent background-image to the 2nd level links in your drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the "primary" div within the "content" div. Try setting a low `z-index` value on `.content .primary`. Honestly, absolute positioning is rarely the best way to achieve a CSS layout like this, and while a more flexible layout could have its own problems, it wouldn't be **these** problems.

Also, the `:first-child` pseudo-class doesn't function very well in IE, so that could be the real source of your bug.

Comment: Only the flyout menu is absolutely positioned , rest of the div have relative position so I could use `z-index` on them to fix the menu hiding under them.

The `.content .primary` has a low `z-index` as you can see in the code in the main post.

The problem appears when you hover the mouse on the flyout at exactly the spot where `.header` ends, so I believe `z-index` may be the source of my problems, I just can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your CSS selectors are selecting what you intended. Unless you're using some CSS hack or something of which I am not aware, `*:first-child+html .content` would select all `.content` elements which are descendants of an `html` element that is adjacent to the `:first-child` of any other element. The `html` element should not be adjacent to any other elements, so I think the `z-index: 1 !important;` declaration is not being applied to anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think it disappears because you have a margin / space set. So when your mouse is hovering that margin/space, you're technically not hovering over the ul. I know, it's weird, and doesn't quite make sense, but IE7 is stupid like that.

To fix it, you need to remove top/bottom margins. Replace them with padding.

It happened to me once, but I fixed it by removing all margins and replacing with padding. Not sure if that will help in this scenario.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using IE7. I finally fixed! My problem was the the fact the IE7 has a problem with display:block. So my link was not in all `li` but just at the actually text inside the `li`. I fixed that putting a width at the 'a' in the css with the same size of the `ul`. Now, it's working! I am so happy that I am looking back every page I was looking the answer for and trying to help people out. if anyone want a better explain, just send me a e-mail. humberto@homemdeasas.com

h!